# The rough road to sweet victory

Tags: riddle

> Up in the sky I am four
>   Once revered in times of war
>   With bloodshed I guard my farm
>   Planting beans to try and charm
>   I closed the door of Opportunity
>   Creating bars for the community

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Mars

Up in the sky I am four

> Mars is the fourth planet from the Sun

Once revered in times of war

> Mars was also the Roman God of war

With bloodshed I guard my farm

> Most of the festivals for the God, Mars, were held in March, the month named for him, and in October, which began the season for military campaigning and ended the season for farming.

Planting beans to try and charm

> Cocoa beans go into making the chocolate [Mars bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_(chocolate_bar))

I closed the door of Opportunity

> The [Opportunity Rover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_(rover))

Creating bars for the community

> Opportunity laid the groundwork for further research and a possible manned mission, the next bars for the human race to clear. 
>  Also could be referencing a Mars bar.

Comment: rot13 (Lbh tbg rirelguvat pbeerpg rkprcg sbe gur ornaf yvar, juvpu vf pbaarpgrq gb fbzrguvat lbh nyernql zragvbarq)

Comment: @JackyWu Is it a reference related to the previous line?

Comment: No, it's related to the last line, I do admit the order of these lines was not perfect but I wanted it to rhyme with the the same syllable count.